# Query access db using silverlight in an oob app with full trust?

Tags: ms-access, automation, silverlight-oob

I was under the impression I could query a local access DB in an out of browser silverlight application. However I'm having trouble finding any information regarding this task.

Is it possible - if so is there any information out there that someone could point me to?